# What is the common way to approximate contour with quad?

Tags: computer-vision

I'm trying to find quads on stream from my webcam. cv2.HoughLinesP sometimes returns more lines then needed. How can I approximate them to contour of exactly 4 points that fits returned result best? I'd like to know the most common way to do this, it looks like an obvious question and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with what is meant by a "quad".  Do you mean a rectangle?  Note that coding questions and OpenCV-specific questions are off-topic here, but algorithms and techniques are OK.  I suggest showing not only the input image, but also a picture showing the lines that are returned.

Comment: @D.W. I meant quadrilateral. Returned lines are drawn on this image with random colors.